# ASP.NET Core environment variables reload configuration on change

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

When using standard appsettings configuration for your ASP.NET Core application there is an option to reload configs on file change by specifying `reloadOnChange` parameter:

```cs
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

When calling `AddEnvironmentVariables()` it allows you to use environment variables as well for generating your config. So the question is if there is a way to set reload on change for environment variables? So my application config is getting reset on environment variable change

Comment: For the filesystem there are watchers which can inform you about a modification of a file, for environment variables there are no such mechanisms. You could poll the content of relevant envirement variables by a scheduler and update settings when the content does change, but this would use some resources.